# Typescript allow only keys from another object

Tags: typescript

I've been trying to type a property that will be defined in child classes as object literals, this object must only contain keys that exist in a generic type.

As an example I have the following base structure

```
interface UserType {
    name: string;
}

class Model<T> {
    protected casts: object
}

class User extends Model<UserType> {
}
```

I'm trying to ensure that the `protected casts` property of model may only contains keys that are present in the generic class, in this case only `name` should be allowed as a key of the `casts` property.

I first thought I could do it using `keyof`

```
protected casts: {[k: keyof T]: string}
```

However typescript rightly informs me that `k` can only have a type of `string` or `number`.

Is there a way that I can achieve my desired outcome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you could use the `Record<K,V>` type from [the TypeScript standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.7.1/lib/lib.d.ts#L1350).  It's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) which represents an object whose keys are `K` and whose values are `V`:

```
class Model<T> {
    protected casts: Record<keyof T, object>
}
```

You can verify that inside `User`, `this.casts` has a `name` property of type `object`.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: This is great, and thank you for the links, very helpful.